# Why isn't தமிழ் spelt "Thamizh"? Or at least "Thamil"?

Tags: indian-languages, tamil

In South India, there is a language called தமிழ். To pronounce it, த is "tha", மி is "mi" and ழ் is "zh". To pronounce "zh", try to imitate a baby saying the letter "r", but add a tinge of the "z".
Anyway, in English, this language is called Tamil. However, the pronunciation dictates that it be called "Thamizlh", "Thamizh", or at least "Thamil". The sound "Th" had been applied in English, so British traders should have been able to convert த to th. Why did they make a mistake and call it "t"? And, as for the letter "ழ்", it was well used in Thamizh, and I do not understand why the British failed to add the letter "zh" or at least convert ழ் into zlh or rlh or zh instead of the least obvious "l". Many fruits, such as மாம்பழம் (mango) have the "ழ்" letter in it. In fact, all fruits end with the word பழம் which means fruit. I do know about the [flourishing Indian Ocean trade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6XtBLDmPA0). When trading fruits and other commodities, the letter ழ் would have been passed on to Southeast Asia, the Islamic World, the Swahili Coast and China. So, when Europeans entered the trade systems during the age of exploration, they would have been exposed to the unique letter. Once they were exposed to it, the started saying it fluently but did not have a letter for it. When transliterating, they would use "zh", although it sounds more like "rlh" in my opinion. So, they were aware of ழ். Why isn't தமிழ் called "Thamizh" or something better than Tamil? Since Tamil is spelt horribly, many Westerners are pronouncing it wrong.

A side question: In other languages, such as Arabic, Chinese, French and Spanish, is தமிழ் transliterated correctly or badly? I would suspect that in Arabic and Chinese, it is transliterated correctly because of exposure through ancient trade.

Comment: I don't speak Tamil, but I thought ழ was sometimes pronounced like the English "L" (IPA `/l/`), depending on dialect?

Comment: If the Wikipedia page on Tamil phonology is anything to go by, Tamil does not have aspirated stops at all, so _th_ does not even exist in Tamil. According to Wikipedia, the sound /ɻ/ is sometimes transcribed as _zh_, but given its pronunciation, that seems rather a suboptimal solution. _L_ is not ideal given the presence of both /l/ and /ɭ/ in the language, but _zh_ strikes me as worse. Also according to Wikipedia, the sound colloquially tends to shift towards [l], so _l_ may not be so very bad after all in a broad transcription.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - According to _Grammar of the Tamil Language_, Andronov M, 1987, Tamil really doesn't have aspirated stops _phonemes_, but the phonemes /p/, /t/, /k/ at the word onset _by some speakers_ are pronounced as aspirated [pʰ], [tʰ], [kʰ].

Comment: @Manu Aspiration means that there’s a little puff of air after the consonant. If you listen to an American or British person saying the words _pin_ and _skin_, you may be able to hear that _kin_ sounds a bit like ‘khin’, but _skin_ does not sound like ‘skhin’. If you’re familiar with Hindi, it’s the difference between त /t/ (unaspirated) and थ /tʰ/ (aspirated). Of these two, the Tamil /t/ is described as primarily being pronounced the same as Hindi त and only by some people sometimes the same as Hindi थ.

Comment: I rolled back this question to its previous version; StackExchange doesn't let users delete questions that have upvoted answers, because upvotes generally mean "this answer is useful or valuable", so we want to keep them around for others who are curious to see.

Comment: @Draconis, I'm very late to this, but, the end ழ is pronounced in two principal ways, generally. These are: 1) 'zh-' imagine a slightly pronounced English 'r' right before the French ʒ sound (ɪrʒ) |  2) 'r'- basically the English r sound- see Wikipedia's entry for Tamil's IPA, the example they use is, literally, தமிழ்- this is the most common pronunciation (ɪɻ) |  In my experience, the only situations in which there's an 'l' sound at the end is when Tamilians speak English in an Indian accent. In those cases, they actually _do_ pronounce the 'l.'

Answer (score 5):

It is all because of the fact that the word "Tamil" got into English not from speakers of Tamil. It got into English from the Pali language and it is a cognate of the word *Dravida*.

The [Online Etymology Dictionary says](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Tamil#etymonline_v_24617):

> 1734, from Pali *Damila*, from Sanskrit *Dramila*, variant of *Dravida*

Actually, I cannot understand why you think த is "tha". It is pronounced [t̪ʌ], [t̪] being dental [t], like in Spanish or in Italian. Also, ழ், [voiced retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_approximant) [ɻ], is acoustically very close to [l], it is even transliterated as <ḻ>. The traditional way to transliterate the word "தமிழ்" is < tamiḻ >, so I won't be surprised to learn that the word "Tamil" was borrowed into English directly from Tamils, with [ɻ] substituted for [l] as the closest-sounding consonant.

In Spanish it is also *Tamil*, in Arabic it is *تاميلية* (tāmīliyya), [in Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B3%B0%E7%B1%B3%E7%88%BE#Chinese) it is 泰米爾 (Mandarin: Tàimǐ'ěr, Cantonese: taai3 mai5 ji5).

**UPD.:** I've found a book with a detailed description of Tamil phonology and phonetics, *Grammar of the Tamil Language*, Andronov M, 1987, in Russian. It states Tamil doesn't have aspirated stops *phonemes*, but the phonemes /p/, /t/, /k/ at the word onset *by some speakers* are pronounced as aspirated [pʰ], [tʰ], [kʰ] allophones. This means that pronouncing த as "tha" is not predominant. Also, *An Intensive Course in Tamil*, S. Rajaram, 1979, which has Tamil words transliterated in Devanagari, has त [t̪a] as the first syllable of "தமிழ்", [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qDdm.jpg).

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the Cantonese name is [淡米爾](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/淡米爾文) _daam6 mai5 ji5_. Etymonline is generally hopeless at properly transcribing non-English languages, but I presume the Sanskrit forms should have retroflex _l̩_ and _d̩_ (those should be dot diacritics, not vertical line, but I can’t find the dot on my phone IPA keyboard).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In Sanskrit it is [द्रमिल](http://sanskritdictionary.com/dramila/106729/1) _dramila_ (no diacritic dot), but [द्रविड](http://sanskritdictionary.com/dravi%E1%B8%8Da/106902/1) _draviḍa_ (with a dot).

Comment: @Manu When you say "TH", is it a continuous sound that you can sustain for a long time (like "S"), or a short one-time sound (like "D")?

Comment: @Manu **huh?** 
ITH + A becomes "Ta".    **த்  + அ = த**

Comment: @Manu As a native Tamil speaker, I don't agree with the "zh" usage. It's quite non-intuitive. The closest would be Tamilh .. There is definitely a **L** sound in **ழ்**. In fact just like how **ந/ன, ண** "deepen" in pronounciation .. **ல, ள, ழ** deepen in pronounciation. Threre is no H .. Pure Tamil doesn't have H, unlike Northern languages or even other South Indian languages.